# Given a radius of 1 for all five circles, find the area of the inner 4-vertex "star" shape.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Four circles, each with a radius of 1 unit, are tangent to each other so that one circle lies fully within each quadrant. Each circle is tangent to exactly two other circles. On top of this configuration, a fifth circle (also with a radius of 1 unit) has a center point at the origin. See the screenshot provided. Find the area of the zone that lies fully within the center circle, and not within any other circle (the "star" shape). I spotted this pattern on one of my coworker’s shirts, and I figured it would be a fun challenge to work out the area of this portion of the pattern. However, it’s proving more difficult than I first imagined. I have a sense that the solution may involve squares and/or right triangles, but beyond that I have no idea.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have added some additional context to the question.

Comment: Draw the square whose vertices are the centers of the outer circles.  It has side length $2$ and area $4$.  Then subtract the area covered by the outer circles... that is four quarter-circles of radius $1$, or one whole circle of radius $1$, with area $\pi$.  The remaining area is $4-\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $r=1$, the area of each circle $\pi r^2=\pi$, and the area of a square circumscribing each circle is $2^2=4$. So each square  exceeds its circle by $4-\pi$, and has one-fourth of this excess in the region within the four circles.

Hence the area of the star is$$4 \left(\frac{4-\pi}{4}\right)=4-\pi\approx.858$$[image: area of star shape]